# Getting a list of unique domains from email list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

Say for example I have a list of emails like:

```
a@domain.com
b@domain.com
c@domain.com
d@sub.domain2.com
g@sub.domain2.com
x@gmail.com
y@analytics.gmail.com
z@yahoo.com
```

I want to get the part after `@` and only get it once (unique).

What I have tried so far:

```
string[] campusCup(string[] emails)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<string>();

    var emailList = emails.Select(x => new { domain = x.Split('@')[1] })
                            .Where(x => hs.Add(x.domain) && Write(x.domain));

    return hs.ToArray();
}
```

my solution does not seem to select anything when I try to debug it.

Comment: Why not use Distinct() linq method. : var emailList = emails.Select(x => x.Split('@').Last()).Distinct();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var domains = emails.Select(email => email.Split('@')[1]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That's perfect! Didn't know I could do that with LINQ. Thanks for your help. Just an additional question if you can help with, if not it's fine. Does this method affect performance for large datasets?

Comment: ...or if you want to ignore case (which is the usual thing to do when dealing with domain names): `.Distinct(
    StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @user9248102 it's not bad on performance. I don't think there any other way that would significantly win on perf.

Comment: @user9248102 *Every* single line costs some nanoseconds. How much is pretty impossible to guess and depends on many different factors.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: @user9248102 no problem :)